# What is "special" about PostgreSQL update vs delete+insert

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, mvcc

My understanding is that an update locks a tuple, marks it as deleted, and then adds a new tuple.

In other words, update = delete + insert.

Or so I had believe. But it appears there something fundamentally different about update from delete+insert in MVCC.

---

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE example (a int PRIMARY KEY, b int);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (1, 1);
```

Method 1: Update

```sql
-- session A                          session B
BEGIN;
UPDATE example SET b = 2 WHERE a = 1;
                                      DELETE FROM example WHERE a = 1;
COMMIT;
-- now there are 0 rows in table example (1 row was deleted by session B)
```

Method 2: Delete and insert

```sql
-- session A                          session B
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM example WHERE a = 1;
INSERT INTO example VALUES (1, 2);
                                      DELETE FROM example WHERE a = 1;
COMMIT;
-- now there is 1 row in table example (0 rows deleted by session B)
```

Thus

```sql
UPDATE example SET b = 2 WHERE a = 1;
```

is different from

```sql
DELETE FROM example WHERE a = 1;
INSERT INTO example VALUES (1, 2);
```

**How am I to understand the MVCC nature of update?** Does the tuple has some sort of MVCC "identity" that is preserved during the update? What is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between `UPDATE` and `DELETE` + `INSERT`.

Let's use the `pageinspect` extension to look at the tuples and the tuple headers.

If you want to repeat my experiment, you have to drop and re-create the table in between. Also, there may be additional flags (hint bits) if you selected the rows before examining them.

The meaning of `infomask2` and `infomask` can be found in [`src/include/access/htup_details.h`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/include/access/htup_details.h;hb=HEAD), see the quotations at the end of the answer.

#### After the `UPDATE`:

```
SELECT lp, t_xmin, t_xmax, t_ctid, t_infomask2, t_infomask, t_attrs
FROM heap_page_item_attrs(get_raw_page('example', 0), 'example');

 lp | t_xmin | t_xmax | t_ctid | t_infomask2 | t_infomask |            t_attrs            
----+--------+--------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------
  1 | 380943 | 380944 | (0,2)  |       16386 |        256 | {"\\x01000000","\\x02000000"}
  2 | 380944 |      0 | (0,2)  |       32770 |      10240 | {"\\x01000000","\\x02000000"}
(2 rows)
```

- The first tuple is the dead one. Its `t_ctid` has been changed to point to the updated version.

  This is one of the key points, so let me expand on this: the `ctid` of a tuple is the combination of the block number and the “line pointer” (`lp` in the query result. `t_ctid` is normally redundant, but in this case it is used to point to the new row version. This is the link between the original tuple and the updated version.

  `t_infomask2` is 2 (the number of columns) plus `HEAP_HOT_UPDATED`, so this row received a [HOT update](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/) (there was enough space in the block, and there is no index). `t_infomask` is `HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED` (a hint bit).
- The second tuple is the new version.

  `t_infomask2` is 2 plus `HEAP_ONLY_TUPLE`, so this is  “heap-only tuple” that is only reachable via the updated `ctid` of the old version. `t_infomask` is `HEAP_XMAX_INVALID` (true, it is 0) plus `HEAP_UPDATED` (this is the updated version).

#### After the `DELETE` + `INSERT`:

```
SELECT lp, t_xmin, t_xmax, t_ctid, t_infomask2, t_infomask, t_attrs
FROM heap_page_item_attrs(get_raw_page('example', 0), 'example');

 lp | t_xmin | t_xmax | t_ctid | t_infomask2 | t_infomask |            t_attrs            
----+--------+--------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------
  1 | 380958 | 380961 | (0,1)  |        8194 |        256 | {"\\x01000000","\\x02000000"}
  2 | 380961 |      0 | (0,2)  |           2 |       2048 | {"\\x01000000","\\x02000000"}
(2 rows)
```

- Again, the first tuple is the dead one.

  `t_infomask2` is 2 plus `HEAP_KEYS_UPDATED` (this is a deleted or updated tuple), and `t_infomask` is `HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED` (the tuple was valid before it was deleted).
- The second tuple is the inserted one:

  `t_infomask2` is 2 plus, and `t_infomask` is `HEAP_XMAX_INVALID` (it is 0), so this is a new tuple.

#### Explanation of the observed difference:

In `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, a transaction always sees the latest committed version of a row. The `DELETE` in session B has to lock the row and is blocked by the `UPDATE` or `DELETE` in session A.

The documentation explains what happens when the lock is released:

> `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, and `SELECT FOR SHARE` commands behave the same as `SELECT` in terms of searching for target rows: they will only find target rows that were committed as of the command start time. However, such a target row might have already been updated (or deleted or locked) by another concurrent transaction by the time it is found. In this case, the would-be updater will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in progress). If the first updater rolls back, then its effects are negated and the second updater can proceed with updating the originally found row. If the first updater commits, the second updater will ignore the row if the first updater deleted it, otherwise it will attempt to apply its operation to the updated version of the row. The search condition of the command (the `WHERE` clause) is re-evaluated to see if the updated version of the row still matches the search condition. If so, the second updater proceeds with its operation using the updated version of the row.

In the case of the `UPDATE` there is a link between the old and the new row version, so PostgreSQL locks and deletes the new row version, while in the case of `DELETE` + `INSERT` there is no valid version of the row after the lock is gone, and nothing is deleted.

So while in many respects `UPDATE` and `DELETE` + `INSERT` are quite similar in PostgreSQL, they are not the same: in the second case, there is no connection between the deleted and the inserted row.

#### Appendix: the meaning of `infomask` and `infomask2`

`t_infomask`:

```
/*
 * information stored in t_infomask:
 */
#define HEAP_HASNULL            0x0001  /* has null attribute(s) */
#define HEAP_HASVARWIDTH        0x0002  /* has variable-width attribute(s) */
#define HEAP_HASEXTERNAL        0x0004  /* has external stored attribute(s) */
#define HEAP_HASOID             0x0008  /* has an object-id field */
#define HEAP_XMAX_KEYSHR_LOCK   0x0010  /* xmax is a key-shared locker */
#define HEAP_COMBOCID           0x0020  /* t_cid is a combo cid */
#define HEAP_XMAX_EXCL_LOCK     0x0040  /* xmax is exclusive locker */
#define HEAP_XMAX_LOCK_ONLY     0x0080  /* xmax, if valid, is only a locker */

 /* xmax is a shared locker */
#define HEAP_XMAX_SHR_LOCK  (HEAP_XMAX_EXCL_LOCK | HEAP_XMAX_KEYSHR_LOCK)

#define HEAP_LOCK_MASK  (HEAP_XMAX_SHR_LOCK | HEAP_XMAX_EXCL_LOCK | \
                         HEAP_XMAX_KEYSHR_LOCK)
#define HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED     0x0100  /* t_xmin committed */
#define HEAP_XMIN_INVALID       0x0200  /* t_xmin invalid/aborted */
#define HEAP_XMIN_FROZEN        (HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED|HEAP_XMIN_INVALID)
#define HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED     0x0400  /* t_xmax committed */
#define HEAP_XMAX_INVALID       0x0800  /* t_xmax invalid/aborted */
#define HEAP_XMAX_IS_MULTI      0x1000  /* t_xmax is a MultiXactId */
#define HEAP_UPDATED            0x2000  /* this is UPDATEd version of row */
#define HEAP_MOVED_OFF          0x4000  /* moved to another place by pre-9.0
                                         * VACUUM FULL; kept for binary
                                         * upgrade support */
#define HEAP_MOVED_IN           0x8000  /* moved from another place by pre-9.0
                                         * VACUUM FULL; kept for binary
                                         * upgrade support */
#define HEAP_MOVED (HEAP_MOVED_OFF | HEAP_MOVED_IN)

#define HEAP_XACT_MASK          0xFFF0  /* visibility-related bits */
```

`t_infomask2`:

```
/*
 * information stored in t_infomask2:
 */
#define HEAP_NATTS_MASK         0x07FF  /* 11 bits for number of attributes */
/* bits 0x1800 are available */
#define HEAP_KEYS_UPDATED       0x2000  /* tuple was updated and key cols
                                         * modified, or tuple deleted */
#define HEAP_HOT_UPDATED        0x4000  /* tuple was HOT-updated */
#define HEAP_ONLY_TUPLE         0x8000  /* this is heap-only tuple */

#define HEAP2_XACT_MASK         0xE000  /* visibility-related bits */
```